# Android sensorPortrait not working for reverse portrait mode

Tags: android, screen-orientation, android-sensors, portrait

I'm trying to make my app work in portrait and reverse portrait modes only (not landscape).
Here are the SDK details of my application

```
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 23
```

In the AndroidManifest.xml file, I have the following line in every activity tag

```
android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
```

I have tried a lot of other answers, but none of them worked for me. Kindly help me out with this.
Thanks.

Comment: sensorPortrait only worked on Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 (API 19). It even failed when I tried it on an API 19 emulator.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's an unsolved bug.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/207403736

When I set android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape", it behaviours as expected.
When I set android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait", it won't change orientation to reversePortrait after my phone turned upside down.
When I set android:screenOrientation="portrait", it can make the right orientation.